# Regexp: remove all tags from string except one kind of tags

Tags: regex, highlighting

I have such string

```
<p>test <span class=\"match\">match</span> <span class=\"testtes\">dddddd</span></p>
```

I want to get string without tags. But I want to save highlighting by class `"match"`:

```
test <span class=\"match\">match</span> dddddd
```

If I want to just remove all tags I substitute all substrings that satisfied regexp `/<\/?[^>]*>/` by empty string. But what regexp should I use in my special case?

UPD: The algorithm is: if you see  and some sentence without tags and then  then you shouldn't remove these spans; otherwise you should remove all tags

Comment: Do not combine regex with html !

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

I can could do someting like this

```
<\/?(?![^>]*class=\\"match)[^>]*>
```

This would preserve the opening tag and result in this

```
test <span class=\"match\">match dddddd
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ubfn)

But how should I find the matching closing tag?

```
<p>test <span class=\"match\">match</span> <span class=\"testtes\">dddddd</span></p>
                                   ^^^^^^^          or the next one?     ^^^^^^^
```

Regex can't know which closing tag belongs to the opening `<span>` tag that contains that class. I don't have the possibility to find matching closing tags. So its not a good idea to do this using regex.

I am quite sure the language you are using has an html parser that can be used to do this task.

Comment: I thought that if I can realize something like finite state machine, then I can write such RegExp. The algorithm is: if you see `<span class=\"match\">` and some sentence without tags and then `</span>` then you shouldn't remove these spans; otherwise you should remove all tags.